# Select a row of a grid

Tags: python, tkinter

How can the user select an entire row of a grid?

In the code below, any cell of the grid is selectable, but not a row. I want the user to be able to select and the be able to ctrl-c to put it in the copy buffer.

```
import os

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkFont
    import ttk

    from Tkconstants import CENTER, LEFT, N, E, W, S
    from Tkinter import StringVar
    from Tkinter import Text

except ImportError: # py3k
    import tkinter as Tkinter
    import tkinter.font as tkFont
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk

    from tkinter.constants import CENTER, LEFT, N, E, W, S
    from tkinter import Text

def displayList(root, frame, zoo_list):

    TOTAL_WIDTH = 225   
    TOTAL_HEIGHT = 200
    dialog_size = str(TOTAL_WIDTH)+'x'+str(TOTAL_HEIGHT)
    root.geometry(dialog_size)

    grid_row = 0;
    for animal in zoo_list:
         try:
            species = animal[0]
            name = animal[1]
            age = animal[2]

         except IndexError:
            print ("[ERROR] IndexError: " + str(grid_row) )

         textProjectId = Text(frame,  width=10, height=1, borderwidth=1) # width and height for Text widget are in characters, not pixels 
         textProjectId.insert(1.0, species)
         textProjectId.grid(row=grid_row, column=0, sticky=("W", "E"))
         textProjectId.config(state='disabled')

         textProjectId = Text(frame,  width=10, height=1, borderwidth=1) # width and height for Text widget are in characters, not pixels 
         textProjectId.insert(1.0, name)
         textProjectId.grid(row=grid_row, column=1, sticky=("W", "E"))
         textProjectId.config(state='disabled')

         textProjectId = Text(frame,  width=4, height=1, borderwidth=1) # width and height for Text widget are in characters, not pixels 
         textProjectId.insert(1.0, age)
         textProjectId.grid(row=grid_row, column=2, sticky=("W", "E"))
         textProjectId.config(state='disabled')

         grid_row+=1   # next project

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

def buildGUI():

    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
    frame = Tkinter.Frame(canvas, background="#ffffff")
    verticalScrollbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=verticalScrollbar.set)
    verticalScrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=frame, anchor="nw")
    frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas:onFrameConfigure(canvas))

    root.wm_title("Python Examples")

    return frame, root

def main():

    print ("[DEBUG]*** Python Examples ***)\n");

    ## data -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    zoo_list = [ ('bear', 'Bob', 11),  
                       ('lion', 'Larry', 4), 
                       ('panda', 'Pete', 5),
                       ('zebra', 'Zane', 7),
                       ('chimpanzee', 'Chet', 2),
                       ('gorilla', 'Gary', 23),
                       ('orangutan', 'Oliver', 46),
                       ('gibbon', 'Glen', 14) ]

    print('\r'.join(map(str,zoo_list)))

    ## GUI ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    frame, root = buildGUI()
    displayList(root, frame, zoo_list)
    root.mainloop()

    print ("\n[DEBUG]*** Done  - Python Examples ***");

# main ###############################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # stuff only to run when not called via 'import' here
    main()
```

Comment: I do not think you can make an `Excel` like window that allows you to select multiple cells. You might be better off storing your text fields in a list and then retrieving each text field in that row and combining the strings. This would be a little harder to build and would likely require a button built on the side of the row to do this.

Comment: So then a different widget (or widgets)?

Comment: As far as I know there is not a widget that supports this function. Tkinter was simply not built to be that complex. If you are always going to have disabled fields then you could probably build something with labels and list.

Comment: Hmph. I don't have to use Tkinter., I'm developing an application with a GUI in python and it seemed to be the most widely used GUI framework. Can you recommend another?

Comment: There are some others that are often used. PyQt comes to mind as another largely used GUI.

Comment: I have added an example of one way you might be able to get each row worth of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code to be able to use a button to select the row. Its a bit crude but should server to show how you can use a list and a button to copy the full row of items.

By adding a list and monitoring the index in your for loop we can create a button for each row that will grab all the values of each row. This is done by saving each value to the new list and referencing the index with a function the button calls on. This can be refined I am sure to something more elegant.

```
import tkinter as tk

def displayList(root, frame, zoo_list):
    global list_of_values_per_row
    TOTAL_WIDTH = 225   
    TOTAL_HEIGHT = 200
    dialog_size = str(TOTAL_WIDTH) + 'x' + str(TOTAL_HEIGHT)
    root.geometry(dialog_size)

    list_of_values_per_row = []

    for ndex, animal in enumerate(zoo_list):
        try:
            species = animal[0]
            name = animal[1]
            age = animal[2]
            list_of_values_per_row.append([animal[0], animal[1], animal[2]])
        except IndexError:
            print ("[ERROR] IndexError: " + str(ndex))

        tk.Button(frame, text="Select", height=1, borderwidth=1, command=lambda x=ndex: append_selection_to_clipboard(x)).grid(row=ndex, column=0)
        textProjectId = tk.Text(frame,  width=10, height=1, borderwidth=1) 
        textProjectId.insert(1.0, species)
        textProjectId.grid(row=ndex, column=1, sticky="ew")
        textProjectId.config(state='disabled')

        textProjectId = tk.Text(frame,  width=10, height=1, borderwidth=1) 
        textProjectId.insert(1.0, name)
        textProjectId.grid(row=ndex, column=2, sticky="ew")
        textProjectId.config(state='disabled')

        textProjectId = tk.Text(frame,  width=4, height=1, borderwidth=1) 
        textProjectId.insert(1.0, age)
        textProjectId.grid(row=ndex, column=3, sticky="ew")
        textProjectId.config(state='disabled')

def append_selection_to_clipboard(x):
    global list_of_values_per_row
    all_row = list_of_values_per_row[x]
    new_string = "{} {} {}".format(all_row[0], all_row[1], all_row[2])
    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(new_string)
    print(new_string)
    root.update()

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

def buildGUI():
    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
    frame = tk.Frame(canvas, background="#ffffff")
    verticalScrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=verticalScrollbar.set)
    verticalScrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=frame, anchor="nw")
    frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas:onFrameConfigure(canvas))
    root.wm_title("Python Examples")
    return frame, root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    zoo_list = [ ('bear', 'Bob', 11), ('lion', 'Larry', 4), ('panda', 'Pete', 5), ('zebra', 'Zane', 7),
                 ('chimpanzee', 'Chet', 2), ('gorilla', 'Gary', 23), ('orangutan', 'Oliver', 46), ('gibbon', 'Glen', 14) ]
    frame, root = buildGUI()
    displayList(root, frame, zoo_list)
    root.mainloop()
```

If you would like something more OOP here is a class version of what you would do with a few more changes I made:

```
import tkinter as tk

zoo_list = [ ('bear', 'Bob', 11), ('lion', 'Larry', 4), ('panda', 'Pete', 5), ('zebra', 'Zane', 7),
             ('chimpanzee', 'Chet', 2), ('gorilla', 'Gary', 23), ('orangutan', 'Oliver', 46), ('gibbon', 'Glen', 14) ]

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        verticalScrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=verticalScrollbar.set)
        verticalScrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.wm_title("Python Examples")
        self.lt = []
        self.displayList()

    def displayList(self):
        TOTAL_WIDTH = 225   
        TOTAL_HEIGHT = 200
        dialog_size = "{}x{}".format(TOTAL_WIDTH, TOTAL_HEIGHT)
        self.geometry(dialog_size)

        for ndex, animal in enumerate(zoo_list):
            tk.Button(self.frame, text="Select", height=1, borderwidth=1,
                      command=lambda x=ndex: self.append_selection_to_clipboard(x)).grid(row=ndex, column=0)
            self.lt.append([tk.Text(self.frame,  width=10, height=1, borderwidth=1),
                       tk.Text(self.frame,  width=10, height=1, borderwidth=1),
                       tk.Text(self.frame,  width=4, height=1, borderwidth=1)])

            self.lt[ndex][0].insert(1.0, animal[0])
            self.lt[ndex][0].grid(row=ndex, column=1, sticky="ew")
            self.lt[ndex][0].config(state='disabled')
            self.lt[ndex][1].insert(1.0, animal[1])
            self.lt[ndex][1].grid(row=ndex, column=2, sticky="ew")
            self.lt[ndex][1].config(state='disabled')
            self.lt[ndex][2].insert(1.0, animal[2])
            self.lt[ndex][2].grid(row=ndex, column=3, sticky="ew")
            self.lt[ndex][2].config(state='disabled')

    def append_selection_to_clipboard(self, x):
        new_string = "{} {} {}".format(self.lt[x][0].get(1.0, "end-1c"),
                                       self.lt[x][1].get(1.0, "end-1c"),
                                       self.lt[x][2].get(1.0, "end-1c"))
        self.clipboard_clear()
        self.clipboard_append(new_string)
        print(new_string)
        self.update()

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event=None):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```